# Loading key to KeyStore fails on Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, android-8.0-oreo

I am using .p12 certificates for signing XML SOAP requests. For loading the certificate I'm using following code:

```
private void loadP12(byte[] p12data, char[] password)  {
    try {
        KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(p12data), password);
        ...
}
```

which works perfectly on pre Oreo Android. However on Android 8 I am getting following exception on **ks.load()**:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key encoding.
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.unwrapKey(PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.java:644)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.java:875)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1484)
    at loadP12(EetRegisterRequest.java:1352)
```

Certificate files can be found here http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/EET_CA1_Playground_v1.zip all of .p12 files have password *eet*.

What could be the problem here? Certificate files should be ok. Could it be similar problem as the one mentioned here http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175251?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I have not...

Comment: If I normalize the certificate by your link (https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175251), then it works. And I informed the publisher :-)

Comment: Resolved, keystore will be fixed by publisher, confirmed by MFCR.

Comment: Could you make this comment as an answer so we can mark this as resolved please? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the certificate. After normalization problem no longer exists.